# date_format function in Hive gives wrong output

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to format date and time down to millis as in the following code:

```
date_format(date_and_time, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as date_and_time
```

However if I am querying the date_and_time value prior to formatting and after formatting I get
two different results:

```
2021-02-03 04:09:14.367 vs 2021-12-31 20:54:20.504
```

Normally I should get same 2021-02-03 04:09:14.367, am I doing something wrong?

This example does have initially milliseconds values but I have some data in the dataset that don't.

Thank you

Comment: It may be bug in your Hive version. Tested in Hive (version 2.3.6), returns the same initial string. Are you selecting from Parquet?

Answer (score 0):

solved by formatting with 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'